# Постоянно вызывается команда "sed" в vs code

Tags: консоль, visual-studio-code, macos, sed

такая проблема...
Настраивал в mac Os Mojave Visual Studio Code для работы с C++
Но после настройки у меня начало сама прописываться команда sed
Вот что пишет в VS code:
[image: Терминал VS Code]

Хотя, если я запущу приложение терминал (Встроенное приложение), то sed нет.
[image: Терминал Mac Os]

Пытался всё переустанавливать, безуспешно.

Answer (score 0):

Решилась проблема!
Необходимо прописать в терминале VS Code

```
brew install gnu-sed  
alias sed=gsed  
ln -s /usr/local/bin/gsed /usr/local/bin/sed
```